# Angular 4 form validation is not working

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, bootstrap-4

I am new to angular 4 ,Here I am trying to implement angular form validation messages in my application .

Here the validation message is get displayed as expected but the text field and label color is not get changed based on the state.

HTML :

```
<form #AddressForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="SaveAddress(mAddress_Model)">
   <div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="Name.invalid && Name.touched" [class.has-success]="Name.valid">
   <label for="FName" class="control-label" >First Name *</label>
   <input type="text" required minlength="4" id="Name" name="Name" class="form-control "  [(ngModel)]="mAddress_Model.mFName"  #Name="ngModel">
    <div class="help-block alert-danger col-sm-12" *ngIf="Name.errors.required && Name.touched">
                    * First name is required
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here `**[class.has-error]="Name.invalid && Name.touched" [class.has-success]="Name.valid"**`   not worked for me but the validation message div is working .

I followed this blog http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2018/01/displaying-angular-form-validation.html

Can anyone help me to solve this .

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Have you inspected the DOM using the browsers developer tools? Is the class being applied, or not?

Comment: <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="form-group has-error">  I get this in console @user184994 I think it's not applied

Comment: Right, so according to that the `has-error` class has been added, it sounds like the style hasn't. Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: yes I am using latest bootstrap in Index.html @user184994

Comment: It looks like the `has-error` class no longer exists in bootstrap 4. You may need to create your own CSS class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your input tag and use `[ngClass]` attribute to change input tag border line to red or any color and same can be done for text too.

```
<input [ngClass]="{'decorate-red' : !mAddress_Model.mFName && flag, 'decorate-regular' : mAddress_Model.mFName && !flag}" type="text" required minlength="4" id="Name" name="Name" class="form-control "  [(ngModel)]="mAddress_Model.mFName"  #Name="ngModel">
```

If there is an error then assign flag value to false else true.

in css add

```
.decorate-red {
   border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use this instead?

```
[ngClass]="hasErros? 'some-class' : 'some-other-class'"
```